# Getting SAP Data onto SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, isapi

This is kind of open question,  we need to understand the options we have for getting SAP data onto SharePoint 2013.

We are willing to use this data onto InfoPath forms,  what could be performance implecations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BCS to pull data into SharePoint from SAP web service without using the third-part tools.

[How to Integrate SAP Business Data Into SharePoint 2010 Using Business Connectivity Services and LINQ to SAP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102453/How-to-Integrate-SAP-Business-Data-Into-SharePoint)

Their are options from 3rd party as well.

[SAP integration into Office 365 and SharePoint](http://www.layer2.de/en/community/FAQs/cloud-connector/Pages/SAP-SharePoint-Office-365-Integration-NetWeaver-OData-Layer2.aspx)

[Business Process Management for SAP on SharePoint](http://innowera.com/sap-sharepoint-integration.php)

[SAP and SharePoint: How to connect native SharePoint lists codeless in just minutes to any SAP data?](http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/community/FAQs/BDLC/Pages/SharePoint-SAP-How-to-connect.aspx)

Comment: thanks Waqas,  this really helps.  We do not have BCS enabled on our environment yet.